# WF4 Ready Instances

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

How can I find out what items in the database are ready to be ran.  In other words, I want to query the persistence tables to identify what items have the lock that expired.  I can't seem to find any fields that would show this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never worked it out either.

I've used workflow.Load and caught the exception; which is nasty but worked.

Comment: Crazy, but thats also what I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

On an `WorkflowApplication` instance, you can use the `LoadRunnableInstance` method which automatically loads the next available workflow in the instance store whose lock has expired.

```
AutoResetEvent sync = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Workflow1 myWorkflow = new Workflow1();
SqlWorkflowInstanceStore instanceStore = new SqlWorkflowInstanceStore("<my connection string>");
WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(myWorkflow);
wfApp.InstanceStore = instanceStore;
wfApp.Completed += (eventArgs) => sync.Set();
wfApp.LoadRunnableInstance();
wfApp.Run();
sync.WaitOne();
```

Comment: So if you want to run all workflows that are ready to run you can open many threads and run this code in each thread and it should work okay?

Comment: Yes, you can definitely do that.

Comment: When I run this, I get this error: The WorkflowApplication.LoadRunnableInstance operation requires an explicitly created InstanceOwner. To use this method, create an instance owner that has a workflow host type and set it as the DefaultInstanceOwner of the InstanceStore.

Comment: How can we use this if we have multiple workflow types in the store?